# Buscar CEP React?

Tags: react

Estou com uma dificuldade em implementar uma consulta por CEP no `React`
O que desejo fazer e o usuário informa o número do CEP no campo `<input/>` e automaticamente os campos do formulário são preenchidos.

O que preciso fazer para que o formulário seja populado com a busca pelo CEP e ao tentar fazer da forma que implementei apresenta o seguinte erro:

> :3000/#/cadastro-clientes:1 Access to fetch at 'https://viacep.com.br/ws/*****-***/json/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.viacep.com.br/ws/*****-***/json/:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

Porém a busca e feita apesar do erro.

```
handleChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    const name = event.target.name;    
    this.setState({ [name] : value })    
    this.buscarCep();
}

buscarCep() {
    if(this.state.cep.length < 9) {
        return;
    } else {
        fetch(`https://viacep.com.br/ws/${this.state.cep}/json/`)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
         this.state.uf = data.uf;
         this.state.cidade = data.localidade;
         this.state.uf = data.uf;
         this.state.bairro = data.bairro;
         this.state.logradouro = data.logradouro;
        });
    }
}

render( ){
    return (
        <Card>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-5">
                    <FormGroup id="inputCep" label="CEP: *" >
                        <InputMask id="inputCep"
                               className="form-control" 
                               name="cep"
                               mask="99999-999"
                               value={this.state.cep}
                               onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                    </FormGroup>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-12">
                    <FormGroup id="inputLogradouro" label="Logradouro:" >
                        <input type="text" id="inputLogradouro"
                               className="form-control" 
                               name="logradouro"
                               value={this.state.logradouro}
                               onChange={this.handleChange}  />
                    </FormGroup>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-12">
                    <FormGroup id="inputBairro" label="Bairro:" >
                        <input type="text" id="inputBairro"
                               className="form-control" 
                               name="bairro"
                               value={this.state.bairro}
                               onChange={this.handleChange}  />
                    </FormGroup>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-6">
                    <FormGroup id="inputCidade" label="Cidade:" >
                        <input type="text" id="inputCidade"
                               className="form-control" 
                               name="cidade"
                               value={this.state.cidade}
                               onChange={this.handleChange}  />
                    </FormGroup>
                </div>

                <div className="col-md-6">
                    <FormGroup id="inputUf" label="UF:" >
                        <input type="text" id="inputUf"
                               className="form-control" 
                               name="uf"
                               value={this.state.uf}
                               onChange={this.handleChange}  />
                    </FormGroup>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Card>
    }
}
```

Comment: deu certo .....

Comment: Benvindo ao SO! A resposta de @novic é um exemplo completo e funcional. Caso tenha sanado dúvidas ou sido importante, sugiro que você marque como resposta, daí outros usuários com a mesma dúvida verão que sua pergunta foi respondida.

Answer (score 1):

Problemas:

- Quanto for utilizar o `fetch` precisa especificar o seu modo de operação que em seu caso e

  ```
  { mode: 'cors' }
  ```

  esse objeto sendo o segundo parâmetro quando o verbo de requisição for `GET`.
- Um outro ponto é que não foi utilizado o método `setState` para mudar o estado antigo para o novo objeto de valores que foi requisitado pela `fetch` e também não coloque os dados de um objeto direto na raiz do seu `this.state` sempre crie chaves, porque, com isso abre para ter novos estados nesse componente.
- Como foi relatado na pergunta, deseja que em um determinada quantidade de números forem digitados (no caso é 8, fato descrito na API) acione a busca dinamicamente, vale muito lembrar que o `this.setState` tem um segundo parâmetro que é uma função e nessa função significa que o estado já foi alterado com isso `this.state.data.cep` já tem todos os números digitados e pode então utilizar a função `this.buscarCep()` para verificar se já pode fazer a sua requisição, do outro jeito o estado ainda não foi alterado cansando problema pela falta de dígitos nesse número.

Fiz um exemplo mínimo:

```js
const dataInit = {
  cep: "",
  logradouro: "",
  complemento: "", 
  bairro: "",
  localidade: "",
  uf: "",
  ibge: "",
  gia: "",
  ddd: "",
  siafi: "",
}
class App extends React.Component {  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      data: dataInit
    }
  }
  url = () => {
    return `http://viacep.com.br/ws/${this.state.cep}/json/`;
  }
  handleChange = (event) => {
      const value = event.target.value;
      const name = event.target.name;    
      this.setState({ [name] : value }, () => {      
        this.buscarCep();
      });
  }

  buscarCep() {
      if(this.state.cep.length < 8) {
          return;
      } else {      
           fetch(this.url(), {mode: 'cors'})
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                if (data.hasOwnProperty("erro")) {
                    this.setState({data: dataInit});
                    alert('Cep não existente');
                } else {
                    this.setState({data});
                }
            })
            .catch(err => consolelog(err));
      }
  }
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <label> Digite o cep:
            <input 
               name="cep" 
               maxlength={8}
               value={this.state.cep} 
               onChange={this.handleChange}
            />           
          </label>
          <div>Endereço/Rua: {this.state.data.logradouro}</div>
          <div>Complemento: {this.state.data.complemento}</div>
          <div>Bairro: {this.state.data.bairro}</div>
          <div>Cidade: {this.state.data.localidade}</div>
          <div>UF: {this.state.data.uf}</div>
          <div>IBGE: {this.state.data.ibge}</div>
          <div>Gia: {this.state.data.gia}</div>
          <div>DDD: {this.state.data.ddd}</div>
          <div>Siafi:{this.state.data.siafi}</div>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```